# Android - Make ImageView Visible When ListItem is selected

Tags: android, android-listview, visibility, android-imageview

I have a listview and each item has a title, some info, and a couple ImageViews I'm using as edit/delete buttons.  I don't want to show these "buttons" unless the user selects the row.  I can make the "buttons" invisible using:

```
        DeleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        EditButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

in my BindView.

I can make the buttons visible in an onListItemClick:

```
    ImageView DeleteButton = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
    ImageView EditButton = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.button_edit);
    DeleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    EditButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

What I can't do is make the "buttons" invisible when selecting another item or scrolling away.

The closest I found was to do a loop through the listitems in the current view and set them all to invisible before making the selected one visible:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    \\loop through all the items and set them back to invisible
    for (int i=0;i<=l.getLastVisiblePosition();i++){
        View vChild = l.getChildAt(i);
        ImageView DeleteButton = (ImageView) vChild.findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
        ImageView EditButton = (ImageView) vChild.findViewById(R.id.button_edit);
        DeleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        EditButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    \\set the selected one visible
    ImageView DeleteButton = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
    ImageView EditButton = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.button_edit);
    DeleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    EditButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

As you can guess...this approach only works if you have a few items.
I thought about adding a field to the SQLite database my list is using to keep track of the button visibility (similar to what you do for checkboxes) but that seemed silly.  Please tell  me there's another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to do this would be to have an `int` field in your class that will remember the current position:

```
private int current = -1;
```

then in the `onItemCLick()` method use that field to hide/show your views:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            // if it is the first click ignore this part
    if (current != -1) {
        View last = l.getChildAt(current); // the last one clicked
        last.findViewById(R.id.button1).setVisibility(View.GONE); // kill it
    }
    v.findViewById(R.id.button1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    current = position; // remember the new clicked position
}
```

If you want the views to be gone also when you scroll the list and those views aren't visible then in the `bindView()` method add the lines that hide the views:

```
//...
ImageView DeleteButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.button_delete); // view is the view that you get as a parameter
ImageView EditButton = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.button_edit);
DeleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
EditButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

//...
```

When the use scrolls the list all the views will have the `Button`s visibility set to `GONE` and the `onItemCLick()` logic will work only for visible views.

Comment: Thanks, that's the idea i needed.  I had thought about trying to keep track of the last row clicked, but I wasn't sure what to do once that row scrolled away.  I didn't realize the bind view could take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i understand your question correct but make the definitions of the ImageViews

```
    ImageView DeleteButton = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
    ImageView EditButton = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.button_edit);
```

one time at onCreate() and not every time again! Dont know if this solves your problem but try it.

Edit:

```
if(tempEditButton != null && tempDeleteButton != null){
tempDeleteButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
tempEditButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
EditButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
DeleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

tempEditButton = EditButton;
tempDeleteButton = DeleteButton;
```

Comment: Since there is more than one set of ImageViews (a set for each item in my list), I have to define the ImageViews as the listview is populated.  So I do this in the BindView (since my list is bound to a SimpleCursorAdapter).  But that gets me thinking.  I'm looking at my NewView Override that isn't doing anything...maybe I could make the buttons invisible in that.

Comment: You dont have to init DeleteButton and EditButton every time new. A private ImageView Editbutton and private

Comment: ImageView DeleteButton in your class definition would do the trick. the problem at the moment is, that you init EditButton and DeleteButton every time new. you dont have to do that! you can give another value in runtime but dont init them as ImageView again as they will be new elements and dont have the propertys you set!

Comment: Thanks for the follow up.  I think I see where you are going.  I can move my declare EditButton and DeleteButton up top and just use them over and over in my bind view.  But I don't see how that solves my problem.  What I have now is a listview and each row has 2 hidden buttons.  When I click on an item, the buttons become visible.  So far so good.  When I click on another row, the buttons on that row become visible...but I want the buttons on the first row to go back to being invisible.  That's what I can't get to work.

Comment: you could init tempEditButton and tempDeleteButton and save the last instances of DeleteButton and EditButton there. So in your Listener:                                                            
Look at my main answer...

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I think I can still answer it. I solved this problem by creating a public static method which can be called from anywhere:

```
public static void hideOptions(Activity activity){
    for (int i = 0; i< listviewSize; i++) {
        Listview x = (Listview ) activity.findViewById(R.id.contactRecyclerView);
        x.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.myView).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

You can then call this method whenever you want to hide your view